# Chroma key software (script)

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, chromakey

I have thousands of small videos in HDTV quality. All with green chroma key.
I need to change green colour for a static image (company logos).

There are several softwares that can change chroma key, but they are only one by one file.
This will take years to be completed.

Is there a software (script) that I can make this automatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with [avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page) it's a simple scripting language for video and can use [avidemux](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php) to edit video interactively or x264 and ffmpeg  to read/write files automatically.

edit: 
see http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/184560-AviSynth-Chroma-Key

The avisynth interpreter loads your file itself, it then spits out the processed frames. If you run the script with the avisynth proxy (included with avidemux) then players like avidemux can connect to the proxy as if they were opening a file and play the processed video.

The [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) commandline H264 codec can also run avisynth scripts, you just supply the script as the input filename (remember the actual source file is inside the script) and it will output the processed, and then H264 coded file to an mp4

the tutorials make more sense than I do .......

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I use FFMPEG to change chroma key with another image? I also couldn't find any reference how to make chroma key with avidemux.